# Google Maps draw mode measure distance

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to implement "Measure Distance" in google maps v3, something like what we can do in [Google Maps Web](http://www.google.com/maps).

[image: Measure Distance]

I wonder if there is a library that implmente this as a drawingMode of DrawingManager.

Answer (score 13):

You can now use this MeasureTool library for Google Maps JavaScript API v3 to do similar to what Google Maps offers.

[Measurement tool for Google Maps API - project page](https://github.com/zhenyanghua/MeasureTool-GoogleMaps-V3)

Here is a live [demo](https://zhenyanghua.github.io/MeasureTool-GoogleMaps-V3/).

Comment: You should add a disclaimer telling that you're the author. Just to avoid someone saying you're self-promoting your tool. Beautiful code, by the way. Cleanest usage of ES6 I've seen in a while.

Comment: Are they the author?

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example I found of a simple ruler that measures distance between two markers:

http://www.barattalo.it/measure-distance-google-maps

The source code is available via a link on that page.

I hope to use the same basic idea in [my own Topographic Maps](http://www.vulgarianramblers.org/big_peak_map.php?latitude=36.5104191&longitude=-118.52267640000002&zoom=15&title=Big%20Arroyo) to drag out a series of markers, then use the resulting PolyLine to draw an elevation profile, etc.  I'll post a reference to my code here if I'm successful.

That said, since this "Measure distance" UI has been part of the standard desktop Google Maps since July 2014, I would hope that the Google team might share it via the published Google Maps API soon, simplifying our work (not to mention standardizing the UI for such user drawn paths).

FYI,

Chris

Comment: Here's [another example](http://exploregooglemaps.blogspot.com.br/2012/02/measuring-distance-with-markers.html) by Heitor Chang supporting multiple points (essentially an attempt to reproduce the Distance Measurement tool after an early version was released by Google Labs).

Comment: You should probably also review [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23893027/capture-google-maps-polyline-on-click-per-start-end/23893147#23893147).

Comment: Sean Kendle's [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Xqaw/12/) provides a decent solution to your problem (including draggable markers), though (again) without the standard look & feel of Google's own Measure distance tool.