# Draw polygon using ngmap

Tags: html, angularjs, google-maps, polygon, ng-map

I'm trying to draw polygon on my map using `ngmap`. The map is displayed correctly as [this](https://ngmap.github.io/#/!drawing-manager.html) example is showing, but when I finish the draw, this is what I'm getting:

```
ng-map.min.js:25 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onMapOverlayCompleted' of undefined
```

I used the same code of the example.

**My questions:**

1- How can I solve this error?

2- If I want to let the user draw only polygon form, I have tried to set the value of `drawingMode` to "polygon" but I'm always having the other draw options (circle...). How can let only the polygon draw?

3- How can I let the user clear the drawn polygon?

4- Is it possible to detect the action of putting (drawing) every points. I mean that to draw a line in the polygon for example I need at least two points. Can I detect when the user draw the first point then the second and get its coordinates?

**Edit**

This is the whole error that I see when I include `ng-map.js` instead of `ng-map.min.js` :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onMapOverlayCompleted' of undefined
    at index (http://localhost:8080/bower_components/ngmap/build/scripts/ng-map.js:2690:44)
    at Array.reduce (native)
    at Uw.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/bower_components/ngmap/build/scripts/ng-map.js:2691:39)
    at P4._.z.trigger (https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&libraries=placeses,visualization,drawing,geometry,places:99:121)
    at P4.<anonymous> (https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&libraries=placeses,visualization,drawing,geometry,places:37:81)
    at C4._.z.trigger (https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&libraries=placeses,visualization,drawing,geometry,places:99:121)
    at C4.<anonymous> (https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&libraries=placeses,visualization,drawing,geometry,places:37:81)
    at Object._.z.trigger (https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&libraries=placeses,visualization,drawing,geometry,places:99:121)
    at F4 (https://maps.google.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/28/14/drawing_impl.js:7:70)
    at G4 (https://maps.google.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/28/14/drawing_impl.js:4:249)
```

**Edit 2**

I solved the first question:

My problem was that I'm using routes in the app.js. So the `html` and the `controller` are linked in it. To solve the problem, I put `$scope.onMapOverlayCompleted` instead of 
`var vm = this;` 
`vm.onMapOverlayCompleted` because I don't write the the `ng-controller="DrawingManagerCtrl as vm"` in my `HTML`. Then in the `HTML` I put `on-overlaycomplete="onMapOverlayCompleted()"` and it works.

I solved also the second question by using:

```
 drawing-control-options="{position: 'TOP_CENTER',drawingModes:['polygon']}"
```

I'm want now to solve the other problems.

Any help please?

Comment: please include `ng-map.js` to see detail  of the error, not `ng-ma-.min.js`.

Comment: @Pengyy please see my edit

Comment: You need to share more of your code for us to be able to help. Especially the controller and HTML containing the map

Comment: It works now thank you. My problem was that I'm using routes in in app.js. So the html and the controller are linked in it. To solve the problem, I put `$scope.onMapOverlayCompleted` instead of `var vm = this; vm.onMapOverlayCompleted` because I don't write the the `ng-controller="DrawingManagerCtrl as vm"`. Then in the html I put `on-overlaycomplete="onMapOverlayCompleted()"`

Comment: @MatejP. please see my Edit

Comment: @Pengyy please see my edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**3**

As the [example you referenced](https://ngmap.github.io/#/!drawing-manager.html) shows, the `overlaycomplete` callback function receives `e` (Event) as the first parameter. This `OverlayCompleteEvent` object contains reference to the drawn overlay at `Event.overlay` (see [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#OverlayCompleteEvent) of the original Google Maps JS API more info, since `ng-map` is only wrapper of the original API after all, specifically "OverlayCompleteEvent object specification" section).

Using that you can get the reference to the created overlay, store it and then later call `.setMap(null)` on it to delete it from map. E.g:

```
$scope.myDrawnOverlays = []; //array where you store drawn overlays
$scope.onMapOverlayCompleted(e){
    ...
    myDrawnOverlays.push(e.overlay); //store reference to the drawn overlay after it's drawn
}
$scope.deleteAllDrawnOverlays(){
    for(var i = 0; i < myDrawnOverlays.length; i++){
        myDrawnOverlays[i].setMap(null); //remove overlays from map one by one
    }
    myDrawnOverlays = [];
}
```

Then whenever you want to delete all overlays, just call the function `$scope.deleteAllDrawnOverlays` (you can tie it to some button using `ng-click` or do whatever you want with it).

**4**

This is NOT possible using `google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager` which is used in your example. The reason is that DrawingManager doesn't support events for clicking at the map while drawing (see [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#DrawingManager) again for possible events, section "DrawingManager class").

So except hacky workarounds which could break any time with new api release, the only possible solution is to implement drawing of polygon yourself and not use `DrawingManager`. Check for example this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23893147/2661226), specifically the [referenced example](http://jsfiddle.net/8Xqaw/12/) (right-clicks on map). They don't use ng-map, but basically what would you have to do is to add `on-click="mapClickHandler"` to your `ng-map`, in the `mapClickHandler` get position where you clicked on map, draw Marker there which would look like a dot and if you have more dots connect them with lines.

This is however too much for one question, you would have to probably read up on `ng-map` and relevant sections of Google Maps Js Api yourself.